# Как задается флаг Privileged в docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

есть флаг docker run --privileged.Как его вставить в docker-compose.yml?

Вот кусок файла с контейнером jenkins для которого нужно сделать privileged

```
 jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    user: '1000'
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wolumes/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST= 
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST= 
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8080  
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте `privileged: true`:

```
jenkins:
    privileged: true
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    user: '1000'
    ...
```

Поддерживается начиная с версии `3.3` `docker-compose`.

Comment: Спасибо,решение верное,но конечную проблему не решило по итогу.

Comment: Ответ содержит решение для проблемы сформулированной в вопросе. Если у вас какая-то другая проблема, то стоит ее описать ;)

Comment: Да,все верно,решение указанной проблемы вы подсказали.Спасибо огромное)С более глобальной проблемой пока пытаюсь разобраться сам.